# how does the "nth-child" work?

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning HTML/CSS and have a difficulty. My HTML is :

```css
header
{
    display: flex;
}

header:nth-child(1)
{
    flex: 1;
    background: white;
}

header:nth-child(2)
{
    flex: 2;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id = "Titre Principal">
        <img src = "images/zozor_logo.png" alt = "Logo de Zozor"/>
        <h1 class = "zouz"> Zozor </h1>
        <h2 class = "hoodie"> Carnets de voyage </h2>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class = "hoodie">
            <li><a href = "#"> ACCUEIL </a></li>
            <li><a href = "#"> BLOG </a></li>
            <li><a href = "#"> CV </a></li>
            <li><a href = "#"> CONTACT </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

The problem is that I get this [image] 
instead of this [image]

What is going wrong ? What theoretical did I missed ?

Comment: You missed the `>`, as in `header>:nth-child(1)`

Comment: Quite weird, in the ttorial i'm following (openclassroom) the code is : `.element:nth-child(1)
{
    flex: 2;
}
.element:nth-child(2)
{
    flex: 1;
}`

Comment: But your trick works :) ! Thanks !

Comment: Sure, but `header:nth-child(1)` means "`<header>` that is the first child of its parent". You want "first child of the `<header>`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header:nth-child(1)
```

means:

For every  element that is the first child of its parent

Which only targets your top most  element. It is the first child of its parent (body)

you could also rewrite this as

```
header
{
  display: flex;
}

div:nth-child(1)
{
  flex: 1;
  background: white;
}

nav:nth-child(2)
{
 flex: 2;
 background: black;
}
```